# Solving an android app crashing in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[Line 68 highlighted flags error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JTeV.png)

I am new to Kotlin and got engaged in a project but the application is crashing after the splash page. The logcat report is shown below:

```
 2020-07-20 14:42:19.389 9849-9970/com.sam.sabinomeals E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
        Process: com.sam.sabinomeals, PID: 9849
        kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
            at com.sam.sabinomeals.commons.Common.updateToken(Common.kt:128)
            at com.sam.sabinomeals.services.MyFCMServices.onNewToken(MyFCMServices.kt:22)
            at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.1:108)
            at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzh.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.1:2)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

The code of the Common.kt file is shown below:

```
package com.sam.sabinomeals.commons

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Build
import android.text.Spannable
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
import android.text.style.StyleSpan
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.sam.sabinomeals.models.*
import com.sam.sabinomeals.R
import java.lang.Exception
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.*

object Common {

   // open class MySwiperHelper(requireContext: Context, recyclerOrder: RecyclerView, i: Int) {

     //   open fun instantiateMyButton(
        //    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
          // buffer: MutableList<com.sam.sabinomeals.commons.MySwiperHelper.MyButton>
     //   ) {
      //  }
   // }

    val NOTI_CONTENT: String? = "content"
    var NOTI_TITLE: String? = "title"
    const val TOKEN_REFERENCE: String = "Tokens"
    var authorizeToken: String? = null
    var currentToken: String = ""
    const val ORDER_REFERENCE: String = "Order"
    val FOOD_REFERENCE: String = "foods"
    const val COMMENT_REFERENCE: String = "Comments"
    var FOOD_SELECTED: FoodModel? = null
    var CATEGORY_SELECTED: CategoryModel? = null
    val FULL_WIDHT_COLUMN: Int = 1
    val DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT: Int = 0
    const val CATEGORY_REFERENCE: String = "Category"
    const val BEST_DEAL_REFERENCE: String = "BestDeals"
    const val POPULAR_CATEGORY_REFERENCE: String = "MostPopular"
    const val USER_REFERENCE: String = "Users"
    var currentUser: UserModel? = null

    fun formatPrice(displayPrice: Double): String {
        return if (displayPrice != 0.toDouble()) {
            val currency = Currency.getInstance("NGN")
            val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
            numberFormat.currency = currency

            numberFormat.format(displayPrice)
        } else
            "0 NGN"
    }

    fun reverformat(price: String): Double? {
        val currency = Currency.getInstance("NGN")
        val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()

        numberFormat.currency = currency
        var priceForm = 0.toDouble()

        priceForm = numberFormat.parse(price).toDouble()

        return priceForm
    }

    fun calculateExtraPrice(
        userSelectedAddon: MutableList<AddonModel>?,
        userSelectedSize: SizesModel?
    ): Double {
        var result = 0.toDouble()

        if (userSelectedSize == null && userSelectedAddon == null)
            return 0.toDouble()
        else if (userSelectedSize == null) {
            for (addon in userSelectedAddon!!)
                result += addon.price!!.toDouble()
            return result
        } else if (userSelectedAddon == null) {
            return userSelectedSize.price!!.toDouble()
        } else {
            result = userSelectedSize.price!!.toDouble()
            for (addon in userSelectedAddon)
                result += addon.price!!.toDouble()
            return result
        }

    }

    fun setSpanString(txt: String, name: String?, txtView: TextView?) {
        val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
        builder.append(txt)
        val txtSpannable = SpannableString(name)
        val boldSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
        txtSpannable.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, name!!.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        builder.append(txtSpannable)
        txtView!!.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    }

    fun createOrderNumer(): String {
        return StringBuilder()
            .append(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .append(Math.abs(Random().nextInt()))
            .toString()
    }

    fun buildToken(authorizeToken: String?): String {
        return StringBuilder("Bearer").append(" ").append(authorizeToken).toString()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    fun updateToken(context: Context, newToken: String) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(TOKEN_REFERENCE!!)
            .child(currentUser!!.uid!!)
            .setValue(TokenModel(currentUser!!.phone, newToken))
            .addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "" + exception.message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
            }
    }

    fun showNotification(
        context: Context,
        id: Int,
        title: String?,
        content: String?,
        intent: Intent?
    ) {
        var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null

        if (intent != null) {
            pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "SabinoMeals"
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "SabinoMeals",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                )
                notificationChannel.description = "SabinoMeals"
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
                notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }

            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        context.resources,
                        R.drawable.ic_restaurant_menu_black_24dp
                    )
                )

            if (pendingIntent != null) {
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

                val notification = builder.build()
                notificationManager.notify(id, notification)

            }
        }
    }

    fun createTopicOrder(): String? {
        return StringBuilder("/topics/new_order").toString()
    }

    fun getDaystoWeek(i: Int): String {
        when(i){
           1->return  "Monday"
           2->return  "Tuesday"
           3->return  "Wednesday"
           4->return  "Thursday"
           5->return  "Friday"
           6->return  "Saturday"
           7->return  "Sunday"
        }
        return "UnKnowDay"
    }

    fun convertStatusToText(status: Int?): String{
        when(status){
            0->return  "Passed order"
            1->return  "Order in progress Delivery"
            2->return  "Delivered Order"
            3->return  "Cancelled order"
        }
        return "UnKnowStatus"
    }

}
```

The code for the MyFCMservices.kt is also shown below:

```
package com.sam.sabinomeals.services



import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import com.sam.sabinomeals.commons.Common
import java.util.*

class MyFCMServices : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        val dataRecv = remoteMessage.data
        Common.showNotification(this, Random().nextInt(),
            dataRecv[Common.NOTI_TITLE],
            dataRecv[Common.NOTI_CONTENT],
            null)
    }
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    Common.updateToken(this,token)
    }
}
```

The code required to understand the first two issues has been laid about above but for the remaining part of the logcat report, they are threadexception errors and I have no idea how to handle them.

Comment: Don't use `!!` unless you are absolutely sure something is not null. `!!` should be avoided. It's impossible to crash with KotlinNullPointerException if you don't use it.

Comment: I could replace it with '?' right?

Comment: Yes, but you then have to deal with it being nullable. For example, you can't add a nullable Double to another number. But you could use a default, like `result += addon.price?.toDouble() ?: 0.0` The way you handle the null case depends on what null actually means in your code and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, that's super clear! But after that correction, another error came up

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please look up the just added photo! Thanks

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Please look up the picture I added, If you could be of some help

Comment: I don't see any errors in your picture.